# How to find a prime number using a function

Tags: python

```
def isPrime(n):
    '''
    checking n is  positive  integer or not
    '''
    val = int(n)
    if(val<1):
        return False
    return  True
```

The purpose of mine is to check if a number is a prime or not. So I think through checking whether the number is a positive integer or not, then will make it to be a test for prime number,

Comment: 8.9 is positive why wouldn't it be? Even if you cast to an int still would be positive

Comment: Are you checking if it's a prime or if it's positive?

Comment: You are not checking if `n` is an integer to not...you are *converting* it to an integer and then checking if *that* integer is greater than 1 (which will return `False` when `n` = `1`).

Comment: Name of function, description and implementation doesn't match.  Is 0 positive?  Should the function do a type check that n is integer?

Comment: Suggest renaming `isPrime` to `is_postive` (node the casing here). I am of course positive - no pun intended - that this is the desired behavior, based on both the docstring and the implementation. *However*, if you do intend to check both whether a number is positive and prime (which you might want, based on the title) you should probably indicate it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, according to title, that the goal is to create a 'is_prime' method, here is a solution, based on Allan Wind's answer. I made a small tweak in the existing code in order to generate the correct results.

```
def is_prime(n): 
  if not isinstance(n, int) or n <= 1:          
      return False
        
  # here is the tweak
  for i in range(2, int(n/2) + 1):   
      if not n % i:            
          return False         
  return True

for i in [-2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8.9]:
  print(f"{i} {is_prime(i)}")

# check the output for a series of integers 
for i in range(-2, 40):      
  print(f"{i} {is_prime(i)}")
```

You may also check this article for an optimized method: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/

Answer (score -3):

To check that something is a whole number, you can for example do `(x-int(x)) == 0`.

Unless you want to make sure it's an `int`, ie the Python type. Which is done with `isinstance(int, x)`.

I would probably check if something is a positive integer in this way:

```
def isPositiveInt(num):
    if (num - int(num)) != 0:
        return False
    if num < 1:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: The purpose of mine is to check if a number is a prime or not. So I think through checking whether the number is a positive integer or not, then will make it to be a test for prime number,